# How to override system keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

The standard ubuntu keyboard shortcuts make me crazy when I am developing in IDE. When I click application specific shortcut I didn't get what I want because ubuntu has the same shortcut and action binding to the system shortcut came in action. 
So, is there a way to increase priority of application specific shortcuts? I'd want to freeze system shortcuts when working in IDE.

Answer (score -2):

Check this out:

> Click the Dash Home icon (or tap Super), type keyboard and press
>   Enter.
>
> Under the "Shortcuts" tab, select "Launchers" on the left panel
>
> Click "Launch Terminal", and it shows "New accelerator..."
>
> Tap Super+R, and it shows Super+R
>
> Click the Close button and try the new shortcut. (Note: In this
>   article, I use Ctrl-Alt-T as a default shortcut to Terminal.)

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-ubuntu-after-installation-ubuntu-1204.htm#Add-Change-Keyboard-Shortcuts